# Add to list nth times depending of element's value

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I want to write a function which will add an element n to a list n times for all elements in an input list.

For example:

```
L = List(2,4,1)
```

Output should be:

```
List(2,2,4,4,4,4,1)
```

I would like to do it with tail recursion. So far, I have written this:

```
 def repeat(numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     def repeat_acc(numbers: List[Int], acc: List[Int], number_acc: Int): List[Int] = {
        if (numbers.length == 0)
           return acc
        else if (number_acc == 0)
             repeat_acc(numbers.tail, acc, numbers.head)
        else
             repeat_acc(numbers, acc :+ numbers.head, (number_acc-1))
        }
        repeat_acc(numbers, List(), 0)
 }
```

The problem is that it leaves out the first element of the list. For this output will be:

```
(4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I know why it happens, but I cannot fix it. I have tried many other ways, but for me it seems that tail recursion do not work here. Some always goes wrong, and I get the wrong result.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: MInor note : never test `numbers.length == 0`, it's expensive (has to traverse the list). You can test `number.isEmpty`, or pattern match  with `case Nil => ... case n :: ns  => ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem gets a lot simpler if you add another parameter to your inner recursive method, representing the current number being added.  You should also familiarize yourself with `match` statements, since they are really powerful in Scala and can help express exactly this type of logic.  Nested `if/else` statements and early `return` statements are considered unidiomatic.  Try:

```
def repeat(numbers: List[Int]) = {
    def repeatAcc(acc: List[Int], curr: Int, rem: Int, numbers:List[Int]): List[Int] = 
        (numbers, rem) match {
            case (Nil, 0) => acc
            case (hd::tl, 0) => repeatAcc(acc, hd, hd, tl) 
            case (_, n) => repeatAcc(acc :+ curr, curr, n - 1, numbers)  
    }

    repeatAcc(List.empty[Int], 0, 0, numbers)
}
```

You might also try to use some standard Scala methods like `List.fill`, which can be used in conjunction with the tail recursion as follows:

```
def repeat(numbers: List[Int]) = {
    def repeatAcc(acc: List[Int], numbers:List[Int]): List[Int] = numbers match {
        case hd::tl => repeatAcc(acc ++ List.fill(hd)(hd), tl)  
        case Nil => acc
    }

    repeatAcc(List.empty[Int], numbers)
}
```

Finally, I understand you're trying to learn about these core concepts, but it should be mentioned that this is really simple with Scala built ins:

```
(List.empty[Int] /: numbers) { case (soFar, next) => soFar ++ List.fill(next)(next) }

numbers.flatMap(x => List.fill(x)(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to do a personalized tail recursive call, but I would recommend the following instead:

```
def repeat(numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    numbers.flatMap(n => List.fill(n)(n))
}
```

The inner function takes the value n and repeats it n times in a list, and then this function is flat mapped onto the original list (a regular map would turn `List(1,2,3)` into `List(List(1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3))`, so we use flat map).  This has the benefit of 'doing it the Scala way' with built in collections functionality.

Comment: Minor nitpick : `List.fill(n)(n)` might be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for help. I would like to use map, zip or other great stuffs(I use it often in Python), but it is for studies and I need to fit the program :P But I find the solution.

Comment: That's really too bad - Scala's built-in features (especially collections functionality and pattern matching) are what make it so nice to use compared to Java.  At the very least, I'd recommend trying to find a good way to do it with pattern matching (if you're allowed), just because that's  the approach that Scala favors.

Comment: Polish universities really loves functional programming, but learning functional programming is really slow(I mean, we are starting from really basic level). For map, zip and pattern matching I have to wait 1-2 week :-)
Yes, that's really funny that Java is not quite good language, but childs of Java are really nice, eg. Groovy. Thanks guys for help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def f(l: List[Int], res: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = {

  @tailrec
  def g(n: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
        if (n == 1) acc
        else g(n - 1, acc :+ acc.head)
    }

if (l == Nil) res else f(l.tail, res ++ g(l.head, List(l.head)))
}

scala> f(List(1,2,3))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the solution. Looks bad, but works. I'm too tired to figure out something better.

Here is my code:

```
  def repeat(numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     def repeat_acc(numbers: List[Int], acc: List[Int], number_acc: Int): List[Int] = {
        if (numbers.length == 1 && number_acc == 0)
           return acc
        else if (acc.length == 0)
            repeat_acc(numbers, acc :+ numbers.head, (number_acc-1))
        else if (number_acc == 0 && numbers.tail != Nil ){
           repeat_acc(numbers.tail, acc, (numbers.tail.head))
        }
        else
           repeat_acc(numbers, acc :+ numbers.head, (number_acc-1))

        }
           repeat_acc(numbers, List(), numbers.head)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, just use fill  + flatMap

```
val result = L.flatMap(x => List.fill(x)(x))
```

for recursive solution :

```
scala>  def repeat(numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def run(nums:List[Int]):List[Int] ={
  nums match {
  case Nil => List.empty[Int]
  case x::Nil => List.fill(x)(x)
  case x::xs => List.fill(x)(x):::run(xs)
  }}
  run(numbers)
  }

scala> repeat(List(2,4,1))
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1)
```